# Virtual overridden function isn't getting called

Tags: c++, virtual

I'm trying a bit with polymorphism with the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    virtual void f() {
        cout << "f from Foo" << endl;
    }
};

struct Bar : public Foo {
    void f() {
        cout << "f from Bar" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    vector<Foo> fooV;
    fooV.push_back(foo);
    fooV.push_back(bar);
    for(auto it = fooV.begin(); it != fooV.end(); ++it)
        it->f();
}
```

I expected that since `f()` is overridden, one of them would print "f from Foo" and the other "f from Bar". However, the output of the program is

```
f from Foo
f from Foo
```

I should also note that I also tried adding the keyword `override` to the declaration of `f()` in `Bar`, since I'm using C++11. It didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    vector<Foo*> fooV;
    fooV.push_back(&foo);
    fooV.push_back(&bar);
    for (auto it = fooV.begin(); it != fooV.end(); ++it)
        (*it)->f();
}
```

To achieve polymorphism advantages you should use pointers or references to derived objects.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
fooV.push_back(bar);
```

copies `Foo` part of `bar` only - a `struct Foo` object ends up inside `vector`. Since the new object is of type `struct Foo` it's no wonder `Foo::f()` is being called later.

You can only store objects of one distinct type in `vector` so for your case you'll have to store pointers to objects instead of objects themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You have a vector of `Foo`. Adding a `Bar` to that vector simply copies the `Foo` part of that `Bar` in to the vector (ignoring the other data).

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<Foo> fooV;
```

As you are creating the vector of Foo then the function of Foo will only be called not of Bar